# Simple Isolated Scope Function Parameters not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to call an isolated scope function. The function is removeFriend(item) takes and item and remove it from an array. It's called from a directive named removeFriend that send in a function method="removeFriend(item)" the item to remove, "method" is the name of the function parameter in the directive notifyParent: '&method'. When I click on the remove button the function of the directive is reached but it dosen't call the parent function.

Here is the code:

Here is the html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading" ng-click="collapse()">{{user.name}}</div>
```

```
<h4>Friends</h4>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='item in user.friends'>
    {{item}}

    <!-- This is the directive with the function I want to call -->
    <remove-friend method="removeFriend(item)"></remove-friend>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the controller:

```
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.a = "abc";
var a = a;



$scope.user1 = {
  name: "Diego",
  address: {
    street: 'Santa Fe 654 2e',
    city: 'Córdoba',
    planet: 'Pluton'
  },
  friends: ['Amigo 1', 'Amigo 2']
}

$scope.user2 = {
  name: "Juan",
  address: {
  street: 'Santa Fe 654 2e',
  city: 'Córdoba',
  planet: 'Pluton'
  },
  friends: ['Amigo 1', 'Amigo 2']
}



 $scope.removeFriend = function(friend) {
    console.log('hello');
    var idx = $scope.user.friends.indexOf(friend);

    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.user.friends.splice(friend, 1);
    }
  }

});
```

This is the directive template:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="confirmRemove()">Remove</button>
```

This is the directive definition:

```
myapp.directive('removeFriend', function() {
 return {
    restrinc: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'removeFriend.html',
    scope: {
       notifyParent: '&method'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

    //Function that calls the parent function removeFriend(friend)
      $scope.confirmRemove = function(){
       console.log('removing');
       $scope.notifyParent();
      }
    }
   }
 })
```

Comment: In `removeFriend` and in your template you use `$scope.user` which isn't defined in the controller

Comment: You right, but still not reaching the the parent function. I don't see the console.log('hello');

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Some things to validate:

- Disable Chrome Cache
- Be sure ng-controller is on the outer most div tags for the scope data (didn't see it above, but assume you left it out?)
- You have a typo for 'restrict'

Check out this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/14qKAyclJUg9uCItLDma?p=preview

I did change `$scope.user1` to `$scope.user` for this example.